# Ambiguous close callback on Stripe Checkout API with loading screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

Is there any way inside the Stripe Checkout close callback to determine how it got triggered?

So for example, I have the following code that gets triggered when someone clicks a checkout button:

```
        // fade in our loading screen
        $("#loading-screen").stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);

        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
            key: STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
            image: STRIPE_ICON,
            closed: function () {
                // if user clicks close button, also hide the loading screen
                $("#loading-screen").stop(true,true).fadeOut(200);
            },
            token: function(token) {
                // post payment info back to the server via ajax
                var data = {
                    action : 'checkout',
                    paymentToken: token.id
                };
                $.post(
                    ajaxurl,
                    data,
                    function (response) {
                        // after response from server, fade out loading screen and update page or trigger error
                        $("#loading-screen").stop(true,true).fadeOut(200);
                        if (response.success) {
                            $("#checkout-form").html(response.output);
                        } else {
                            alert("unknown error. try again later.");
                        }
                    },
                    "json"
                );

            }
```

The idea here is when I click the close button on the payment window, or once I get some sort of response from my server, the loading screen goes away.

However, it appears that the *closed* callback is getting triggered not only when someone hits the close button, but also after a payment successfully completes on Stripe's end, but before my ajax call completes.

As a result, the loading screen gets removed prior to the operation's completion, which is confusing users. Obviously things can be done to optimize the slow commands server-side, but I want to try to fix this on the client-side as well.

So basically, I need to find a way to distinguish between closing via the cancel button, and closing via a successful payment and unfortunately the [Stripe Checkout Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) doesn't provide a whole lot of details on that process.

Any suggestions?

---

**Update:**

I think I may have found a way to do it, but it's contingent on the token callback always happening before the closed callback.

Basically I just set a flag that indicates whether the token callback was triggered.

```
        var token_triggered = false;

        // fade in our loading screen
        $("#loading-screen").stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);

        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
            key: STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
            image: STRIPE_ICON,
            closed: function () {
                // if user clicks close button, also hide the loading screen
                if (!token_triggered) {
                    $("#loading-screen").stop(true,true).fadeOut(200);
                }
            },
            token: function(token) {
                token_triggered = true;
                // post payment info back to the server via ajax
                var data = {
                    action : 'checkout',
                    paymentToken: token.id
                };
                $.post(
                    ajaxurl,
                    data,
                    function (response) {
                        // after response from server, fade out loading screen and update page or trigger error
                        $("#loading-screen").stop(true,true).fadeOut(200);
                        if (response.success) {
                            $("#checkout-form").html(response.output);
                        } else {
                            alert("unknown error. try again later.");
                        }
                    },
                    "json"
                );

            }
```

In the few tests I've done, it has seemed to work okay, but does anybody know if there are any guarantees that token will always trigger before closed?

---

**Update #2:**

Upon asking in the #stripe channel on freenode, I was told [as of April 6, it appears Stripe has ensured that token always will fire prior to closed.](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.stripe.com/forum/#!msg/api-discuss/nWxv-ysn0B8/Izgmcypq12IJ)

So I believe this solves my problem and allows me to distinguish between the two events.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As I indicated in my updates above, as of April 6, 2015 the token callback should always fire prior to the closed callback. This means we can set a flag to indicate whether or not the token callback was ever triggered, allowing us to distinguish between the events.

```
var token_triggered = false;
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
     ...
     closed: function() {
          if (!token_triggered) {
              // close button click behavior goes here
          } else {
              // payment completion behavior goes here
          }
     },
     token: function(token) {
          token_triggered = true;
     }
     ...
});
```

Comment: One issue: When using the token callback, the form would never been submitted

Comment: Works like a charm on mobile and desktop. Thank you